# Sending a message from one actor to another actor

Tags: scala, akka

I'm new to Scala AKKA and am trying to code some simple examples. I have a simple example where a price update event is supposed to trigger a position update event. Here is the code:

```
import akka.actor.{Props, ActorSystem}

object Main {

   def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

   val system = ActorSystem("system")

   val priceActor = system.actorOf(Props[PriceActor], "priceActor")
   val positionActor = system.actorOf(Props[PositionActor], "positionActor")

   priceActor ! "Update Price"

   }

}


class PositionActor extends Actor {

   val log = Logging(context.system, this)

   def receive = {

       case "Update Position" => log.info ("Position Updated")
       case _ => log.info("Received an unknown message")

   }

}

class PriceActor extends Actor {

    val log = Logging(context.system, this)

    def receive = {

        case "Update Price" => context.actorSelection("akka://system/user/positionActor")  ! "Update Position"
        case _ => log.info("Received an unknown message")

    }

}
```

Questions:

1. Is it better to create PositionActor inside of PriceActor?
2. In PriceActor, if I wanted to log a message that the price has been updated *and* send a message to PositionActor simulataneously, how would I do that?

Comment: Please tidy up your code. The indentation is all over the map!

Answer (score 0):

2) The body of your `case` can contain more than one statement:

```
def receive = {

  case "Update Price" => 
    context.actorSelection("akka://system/user/positionActor")  ! "Update Position"
    log.info("Price updated!)
  case _ => log.info("Received an unknown message")

}
```

1) It depends on the logic of your application, if you see `PriceActor` as the logical parent or supervisor of `PositionActor` then yes. Otherwise, it's better to create it in your `main` and pass it as a constructor argument to `PriceActor`:

```
val positionActor = system.actorOf(Props[PositionActor], "positionActor")
val priceActor = system.actorOf(Props(classOf[PriceActor], "priceActor", positionActor))

class PriceActor(positionActor: ActorRef) extends Actor
```

I think it's cleaner than looking up the actor in the context.

Comment: Typically the position should always be updated on a new price event so, yes, the PriceActor is the logical parent of PositionActor. In general then, is it good practice to use this type of reasoning to setup the actor system structure?

Comment: In your other comment you say that you want both actors to be independent, then `PriceActor` should not be `PositionActor`. Creating an actor implies being its parent and supervisor, if `PriceActor` is not concerned about `PositionActor` lifecycle then it should not be its parent.

Answer (score 0):

I would not nest one `Actor` subclass within another (probably ever—but tomorrow I could encounter the situation that leads me to do it anyway…). Doing so would make the inner one a dependent type of the outer one. Instances of the inner one could not exist independent of an instance of the outer one. Given the restrictions on Actor subclass instantiations, it  might be difficult to set up the actor system you need with that arrangement.

I'm not quite sure what you're asking in question (2). You can simply:

```
def receive = {
  case "Update Price" =>
    log.info("Updating price")
    positionActor ! "Update Position"
  …
}
```

By the way, I hope you're using proper message types and not `String` for your inter-actor messaging and what you show here is for illustrative purposes only. It seems that must be the case since your messages don't carry any parameters (price or position). While there are cases where messages are constants (heartbeats, e.g.), in any system at least some of them bear some kind of information content other than the message value or type itself.

Comment: Yes, this is the reason why I posted this simple example. I am not sure what is the best practice. You highlight the concern I do have which is that the PositionActor now becomes dependent the PriceActor. Ideally I would like their liveness to be independent of each other. So you seem to be in favour of grabbing a reference to the PositionActor object as I have done or passing by constructor as @vptheron has done?

Comment: If your actor topology is fixed, then it doesn't matter how the upstream actor gets its reference to the downstream one. But if there are multiple actor networks or the topology of message sending is in any way dynamic, you'll need to somehow supply it to the sending actor. That could be by passing the `ActorRef` as a constructor parameter, passing the actor's path name as a constructor parameter or even by sending it a message saying "send your position updates here" (where "here" likewise can be an `ActorRef` or an actor path name).